# Physical meaning of $F^{0\nu}j_\nu$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, tensor-calculus

In my problem I showed that $F^{\mu\nu}j_\nu$ is a contravariant 4-vector. Now the question is what is its 0-component's physical meaning, i.e. the meaning of $F^{0\nu}j_\nu$ if $F^{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic tensor and $j$ the 4-current $(\rho,\vec{j})$. From the definition of $F^{\mu\nu}$ I know that $$F^{0\nu}j_\nu = -\vec{E}\cdot\vec{j},$$ but I can't figure out what the physical significance of this is.

Comment: It's the rate of work being done.

Comment: @knzhou Can you explain why, I don't understand how you get rate of work from that. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: dimensional analysis gives power/volume (measurable in Watt/m$^3$)

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I know that E times charge is force and j is charge per time per area, so I would have $force/(area \cdot time)$ or better $Energy/(time \cdot volume)$ and therefore what you said. But is this then the work the electric field does per volume element, or is there a better or more physically correct way of saying it?

Comment: hint: $EJ = \frac{V}{\ell} \frac{I}{A} = \frac{VI}{vol} = \rm{dissipation \ per \ unit \ volume}$

Comment: @Frobenius you're right, I changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must see your expression as $\:\:\mathrm{P}\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{j}\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\rho\,\mathbf{u}\:\:$ where $\mathbf{E}$ the electric field intensity 3-vector, $\mathbf{j}\boldsymbol{=}\rho\,\mathbf{u}$ the electric current density 3-vector, $\rho$ the electric charge density and $\mathbf{u}$ the charge velocity 3-vector. Then $\mathrm{P}$ is the work  done per unit time (that is power) per unit volume.

---

This is rate of energy per unit volume produced or absorbed by the application of the electric force on the moving charges. The infinitesimal work done ($\boldsymbol{+}$ if produced,$\boldsymbol{-}$ if absorbed) by the application of a force $\mathbf{F}$ on a particle moving infinetisimally by $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$ is $\mathrm{dw}\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$. If this motion takes place in time $\mathrm{d}t$ then we have work per unit time (that is power) $\mathrm{dp}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{dw}/\mathrm{d}t\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}/\mathrm{d}t\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}/\mathrm{d}t$ the velocity of the particle.

For a group of particles of infinitesimal electric charge $\mathrm{d}Q$ constrained in an infinitesimal volume $\mathrm{d}V$ and moving in an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ with velocity $\mathbf{u}$ then $\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{d}Q\,\mathbf{E}$ and the work done per unit time (power) per unit volume is $\mathrm{P}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{d}Q/\mathrm{d}V\,\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{=}\rho\,\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{u}$ where $\rho\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{d}Q/\mathrm{d}V$ the electric charge volume density.